# Issue Including SDL2 and SDL2_image With CMake

Tags: c, cmake, sdl-2

## The Problem

- SDL2_image is unable to locate `SDL.h` from SDL2.
- References to SDL2 within the project files are able to locate SDL2 and SDL2_image.

## CMakeLists.txt

```
# Minimum CMAKE Version Requirement
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.3)

# Find Modules - SDL2
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

# Project Fields - TEST PLATFORM
project(library_test
    LANGUAGES C
    VERSION 0.1.0
)

set(SDL2_LIBRARY "C:/lib/SDL2-2.0.14/i686-w64-mingw32/bin")
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/lib/SDL2-2.0.14/i686-w64-mingw32/include")

set(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY "C:/lib/SDL2_image-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/bin")
set(SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/lib/SDL2_image-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)

# C99 Standard Requirement
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# RESET Library Content
add_library(reset STATIC)
target_link_libraries(reset SDL2::Main SDL2::Image)
target_include_directories(reset PUBLIC include/reset)
add_subdirectory(src)

# Test Platform Content
add_executable(test_platform test_platform/test_platform.c)
target_link_libraries(test_platform STATIC reset)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -ggdb")
```

## CMake Build Output

See the full output here:

```
[main] Building folder: reset 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/C99/reset/build --config Debug --target all -j 6 --
[build] -- Configuring done
[build] -- Generating done
[build] -- Build files have been written to: C:/C99/reset/build
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target reset
[build] [ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/data/provider.c.obj
[build] [ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/data/rrcon.c.obj
[build] [ 30%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/internal/rsetup.c.obj
[build] [ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/spatial/rlevelmap.c.obj
[build] [ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/spatial/rtilemap.c.obj
[build] [ 60%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/visual/rfocus.c.obj
[build] In file included from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/depn.h:12:0,
[build]                  from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/provider.h:13,
[build]                  from C:\C99\reset\src\data\provider.c:2:
[build] C:/lib/SDL2_image-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h:27:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
[build]  #include "SDL.h"
[build]                  ^
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] In file included from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/depn.h:12:0,
[build]                  from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/rrcon.h:15,
[build]                  from C:\C99\reset\src\data\rrcon.c:4:
[build] C:/lib/SDL2_image-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h:27:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
[build]  #include "SDL.h"
[build]                  ^
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] CMakeFiles\reset.dir\build.make:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/data/provider.c.obj' failed
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/data/provider.c.obj] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[build] CMakeFiles\reset.dir\build.make:90: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/data/rrcon.c.obj' failed
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/data/rrcon.c.obj] Error 1
[build] In file included from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/depn.h:12:0,
[build]                  from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/rsetup.h:11,
[build]                  from C:\C99\reset\src\internal\rsetup.c:2:
[build] C:/lib/SDL2_image-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h:27:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
[build]  #include "SDL.h"
[build]                  ^
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] CMakeFiles\reset.dir\build.make:120: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/internal/rsetup.c.obj' failed
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/internal/rsetup.c.obj] Error 1
[build] In file included from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/depn.h:12:0,
[build]                  from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/rlevelmap.h:5,
[build]                  from C:\C99\reset\src\spatial\rlevelmap.c:2:
[build] C:/lib/SDL2_image-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h:27:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
[build]  #include "SDL.h"
[build]                  ^
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] CMakeFiles\reset.dir\build.make:135: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/spatial/rlevelmap.c.obj' failed
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/spatial/rlevelmap.c.obj] Error 1
[build] In file included from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/depn.h:12:0,
[build]                  from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/rtilemap.h:9,
[build]                  from C:\C99\reset\src\spatial\rtilemap.c:2:
[build] C:/lib/SDL2_image-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h:27:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
[build]  #include "SDL.h"
[build]                  ^
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] CMakeFiles\reset.dir\build.make:150: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/spatial/rtilemap.c.obj' failed
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/spatial/rtilemap.c.obj] Error 1
[build] In file included from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/depn.h:12:0,
[build]                  from C:/C99/reset/include/reset/rfocus.h:11,
[build]                  from C:\C99\reset\src\visual\rfocus.c:2:
[build] C:/lib/SDL2_image-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h:27:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
[build]  #include "SDL.h"
[build]                  ^
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] CMakeFiles\reset.dir\build.make:165: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/visual/rfocus.c.obj' failed
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/visual/rfocus.c.obj] Error 1
[build] CMakeFiles\Makefile2:169: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/reset.dir/all' failed
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/reset.dir/all] Error 2
[build] Makefile:89: recipe for target 'all' failed
[build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

The current CMake setup resolved previous issues I had with `#include <SDL.h>` causing a file not found error, but now this occurs within SDL_image as it tries to access SDL. Note that the source of the errors is `SDL_image.h` as it attempts to `#include "SDL.h"`.

Currently, the SDL packages are found using some FindSDL2 cmake files that I found on this page: https://edgarluque.com/blog/sdl2-cmake

This is also the first page I found that actually resolved any of the previous errors I have had. I am on windows instead of linux so there are naturally issues.

I did try adding `-l` compiler arguments for the SDL components but these seemingly had no effect.

## Attempted Solutions

I tried changing the last line in the CMake_lists.txt file (compiler flags):

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -ggdb -IC:/lib/SDL2-2.0.14/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2")
```

and this produced a different error:

```
[main] Building folder: reset 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/C99/reset/build --config Debug --target all -j 6 --
[build] -- Configuring done
[build] -- Generating done
[build] -- Build files have been written to: C:/C99/reset/build
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target reset
[build] [ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/data/provider.c.obj
[build] [ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/data/rrcon.c.obj
[build] [ 30%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/data/rvector.c.obj
[build] [ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/internal/rsetup.c.obj
[build] [ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/spatial/rlevelmap.c.obj
[build] [ 60%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/spatial/rtilemap.c.obj
[build] [ 70%] Building C object CMakeFiles/reset.dir/src/visual/rfocus.c.obj
[build] [ 80%] Linking C static library libreset.a
[build] [ 80%] Built target reset
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target test_platform
[build] [ 90%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_platform.dir/test_platform/test_platform.c.obj
[build] [100%] Linking C executable test_platform.exe
[build] c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2main
[build] c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2
[build] c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2_image
[build] CMakeFiles\test_platform.dir/objects.a(test_platform.c.obj): In function `main':
[build] C:/C99/reset/test_platform/test_platform.c:18: multiple definition of `main'
[build] c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
[build] c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSTATIC
[build] c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:/lib/SDL2_image-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/bin: Permission denied
[build] c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:/lib/SDL2-2.0.14/i686-w64-mingw32/bin: Permission denied
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] CMakeFiles\test_platform.dir\build.make:101: recipe for target 'test_platform.exe' failed
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [test_platform.exe] Error 1
[build] CMakeFiles\Makefile2:195: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/test_platform.dir/all' failed
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_platform.dir/all] Error 2
[build] Makefile:89: recipe for target 'all' failed
[build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Here is also the test_platform.c file, because it is relevant to the new error:

```
//#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

#include "depn.h"
#include "rsetup.h"
#include "rrcon.h"
#include "provider.h"
#include "rfocus.h"
#include "rvector.h"
#include "rtilemap.h"
#include "rlevelmap.h"

#undef main

/// Main Function

int main ( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    fprintf ( stderr, "Received %d argument%s:\n", argc, argc == 1 ? "" : "s" );

    forsi ( argc ) fprintf ( stderr, "\t%s\n", argv [ ix ] );

    CFG_WIN cfg =
    {
        1920, 1080,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        "Reset"
    };

    r_sdlset(); // SDL2 module init

    DATA_WIN display = r_dispset ( cfg );

    RRCON rrcon = rrcon_inst ( display.renderer, TEXTURE );
    register_directory ( "tile" );
    rrcon_import ( rrcon, "grass", "grass.png" );

    RTILEMAP tilemap = rtilemap_static ( );
//    RTILEMAP tilemap = rtilemap_dynamic ( 72, 72 );
    RTILE tile = rtile_inst ( "grass" );

    VEC2U pos = { 0, 0 };
    VEC2U pos2 = { 63, 31 };

    rtilemap_set ( tilemap, tile, pos );
    rtilemap_set ( tilemap, tile, pos2 );

//    RFOCUS focus = rfocus_inst ( F_FLAT_TILEMAP );
//
//    focus -> tilemap = tilemap;

    VEC2I tilemap_start = { 30, 0 };

    SDL_Event ev;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        if ( SDL_WaitEvent ( &ev ) )
        {
            if ( ev.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                rrcon_clr ( rrcon );

                SDL_DestroyRenderer ( display.renderer );
                SDL_DestroyWindow ( display.window );
                SDL_Quit ();
                IMG_Quit ();

                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
        }

        // SDL_SetRenderDrawColor ( display.renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 );
        SDL_RenderClear ( display.renderer );

        rtilemap_render_tiles ( tilemap, rrcon, tilemap_start, 1.0 );

        SDL_RenderPresent ( display.renderer );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` != `CMAKE_LINK_FLAGS`  and anyway use `link_libraries()`. And anyway, try using variables instead of `SDL2::Image` like ex. [here](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/07/04/using-sdl2-image-with-cmake/). Use `find_package(.. PATHS the/path/to/library)`

Comment: @KamilCuk Use `link_libraries()` how? Instead of `target_link_libraries()`? I'm not sure which flags I should be giving to the linker versus the compiler for this to work. Also not sure how I would use a variable instead of SDL2::Image, because I don't know what SDL2::Image actually represents. I am very new to cmake.

Comment: `Use link_libraries() how?` Isntead of `set(CMAKE_SOMETHING -lsomething)` prefer `link_libraries(something)` before defining the executable or library, or yet better, use `target_link_libraries`. `what SDL2::Image actually represents` A interface target. The link I've given has an example, try `target_link_libraries(Exe ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Using `link_libraries` before the library and executable yields the same error output as the initial `target_link_libraries` after the library `reset` is defined (SDL_image cannot find SDL).

I will take a closer look at your edits.

Comment: Then maybe there's something wrong with `SDL2::Main`. Try variables - `target_include_directories(exe PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS})`. Check if these variables are empty or not. I do not have `SDL::Main` on my system  - I have `SDL::SDL`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Where do I check if they are empty? Environment variables? I don't have any different output with the variables, image still can't resolve SDL.h. Is there anything else wrong with the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: `SDL.h` is [usually] under the `SDL2` subdir (e.g. `/usr/include/SDL2` for posix systems). So, you have to do either (1) `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` or (2) add `/SDL2` to the end of `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR` I'm not too familiar with `cmake` but adding the package should be able to set the requisite directories without you having to hardwire them up manually (e.g. It would use the equiv of `pkg-config` to have the package say where to look and similarly for finding the lib directories)

Comment: No. Do not use `link_libraries` or _any_ directory function _ever_. Only use the `target_*` prefixed versions.

Answer (score 1):

After looking over your information and the modules' documentation, here are the issues I'm seeing:

**`CMAKE_C_FLAGS`:**

Avoiding direct manipulation of this in modern CMake solutions is strongly encouraged. CMake provides specialized functions for defining things like compiler flags, linker libraries, etc. and their relationships to specific targets in your project, which allow it to manage things more carefully.

**`SDL2_` variables:**

According to the documentation at https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-cmake-modules these should be cache variables rather than local ones. I'm not sure if this actually matters, but it may be worth noting for troubleshooting purposes. It's also just a good idea in general to use cache variables for this kind of thing, because then people can override them on the CMake command line or in `cmake-gui`.

Note that cache variable values get stored in a CMakeCache.txt file in your build directory, which will likely need to be deleted if you want to use different values.

I should also point out here that the modules' documentation suggests that you should be able to just set `SDL2_PATH` and `SDL2_IMAGE_PATH`. However, this apparently requires that the libraries be under `lib/` in your installation, rather than under `bin/`.

**`SDL2_LIBRARY`/`SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY`:**

If you choose to stick with defining these directly, I think you *may* need to point them at the full path *and filename* of the actual library file, and not just the containing directory.

**`SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR`/`SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR`:**

It appears that these are meant to point to the `SDL2` directories containing the actual library headers (e.g. `SDL.h`), and not to the parent directory containing the `SDL2` directory. This is likely why SDL2_image is failing to find `SDL.h` during compile time.

This also means you are expected to omit `SDL2/` path prefixes from the `#include` directives in your own code; however, you could use `target_include_directories` to add `${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}/..` etc. to each dependent target that you're building in order to end up with both directory levels in the compiler's header search paths.

**`SDL::Core` and `SDL::Main`:**

The module documentation suggests that any SDL-dependent libraries you're building (e.g. `reset`) must link against `SDL::Core`, not `SDL::Main`.

Only SDL-dependent executables (e.g. `test_platform`) that you're building should link against `SDL::Main`, as this represents the library that wraps your `main()` (or similar OS-specific) function with SDL's main function.

Note that if you were only to build an application and not a library, you would only need to link `SDL::Main` because the module defines an internal dependency on `SDL::Core`.